# This VBS file is not working

Tags: vbscript

I've been searching on the internet to find the return value of cancel, [X], etc., but it won't work. Even when I set

```
x = ""
x = " "
x = 0
x = "0"
```

They all don't work!

```
Function check(x)
    If IsNumeric(x) Then
    ElseIf x = "" Then
        WScript.Quit
    Else
        MsgBox "Your input is not valid!", 0+48, "Error!"
    End If
End Function

MsgBox "Welcome to the Calculator! This is a basic calculator for users to use.", 0+65, "Calculator"

a_main = InputBox("Type in any number from range 2-2!", "Number", "2")
check a_main

n_one = InputBox("Type in any and only computational math!", "1st number", "345")
check n_one

n_two = InputBox("Type in any and only computational math!", "2nd number", "2356")
check n_two

ans = CInt(n_one) + CInt(n_two)

WScript.Echo ans
```

Comment: CLOSE IT! I found out that the order matters! So now I know! No need any more answers! I do have another question if VBScript has to be in order then is VBScript case-sensitive?

Comment: Vbscript variable names function names are not case sensitive. Not sure what do you mean by 'VBScript has to be in order'